# Backwards shift operator is bounded linear operator on Bergman space.

Tags: functional-analysis

Following is Exercise 3.24 from Elementary Functional Analysis by Barbara MacCluer

> Show that the operator $$Bf=\frac{f-f(0)}{z}$$ is bounded linear operator on the Berman space $L_{a}^{2}(\mathbb{D})$.

I assume I have to use the [closed graph theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_graph_theorem) as this exercise is from the chapter that explains the closed graph theorem, but how do I prove this?

Answer (score 2):

You can show boundedness directly. Suppose $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$, then $Bf(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n+1} z^n$. Recall:
$$\left\lVert f\right\rVert^2_{L^2_a} = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_\mathbb{D} \left|f(z)\right|^2 dA(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\left|a_n\right|^2}{n+1} $$
so
$$\left\lVert Bf\right\rVert^2_{L^2_a} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\left|a_n\right|^2}{n} \leq 2\left\lVert f\right\rVert^2_{L^2_a}$$

If you specifically want to use closed graph theorem, take an arbritrary sequence $\{f_n\}$ so that $(f_n,Bf_n)$ converges to some limit $(f,g)$ in $L^2_a\times L^2_a$ (Of course, you should first show that $Bf:L^2_a \to L^2_a$ is well defined, which probably takes you 80% through the previous computation anyway). Then try to show that $g=Bf$. By comparing the power series coefficients of $f_n,f,Bf_n$ and $Bf$, this should be somewhat obvious.

Comment: Would you be able to show me more details on using closed graph theorem?

Comment: Convergence on $L^2_a$ implies locally uniform convergence by the mean value property. This in turn tells you that the coefficients of $f_n$ must converge to the coefficients of $f$, and likewise the coefficients of $Bf_n$ converge to the coefficients of $g$ (but also $Bf$). In particular $Bf=g$.

Answer (score 2):

The closed graph theorem proof is very easy, and "better" then the direct proof since it immediately proves the theorem for $1 \leq p < \infty$  (I absolutely love MacCluer's book, but it's weird she doesn't really talk about the Bergman space $L_a ^p(\mathbb{D})$ for $1 \leq p < \infty$.) Note implicitly here we have $Bf(0) = f'(0)$ so there's no issue with $B$ being well defined. Also that $Bf \in L_a ^p(\mathbb{D})$ if $f \in  L_a ^p(\mathbb{D})$ if fairly trivial since $Bf$ is holomorphic (and thus continuous) on $\mathbb{D}.$

Assume $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $L_a ^p(\mathbb{D})$ and $Bf_n \rightarrow g$ in $L_a ^p(\mathbb{D})$.   Convergence in $L_a ^p(\mathbb{D})$ implies uniform convergence on compact subsets of $\mathbb{D}$, and thus pointwise convergence.  Thus $f_n(z) \rightarrow f(z)$ and $Bf_n(z) \rightarrow g(z)$ for each $z \in \mathbb{D}$.

Trivially for $z \in \mathbb{D} \backslash \{0\}$  we have $Bf_n(z) \rightarrow Bf(z)$ so $Bf(z) = g(z)$ for all $z\in \mathbb{D} \backslash \{0\}$ and thus by continuity, $Bf(z) = g(z)$ for all $z \in \mathbb{D}$.  This is exactly what's needed to show (via the closed graph theorem) that $B$ is bounded on