# Concrete example of a weakly bounded subset of a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, complex-analysis

I'm teaching a basic functional analysis course and have a question I can't seem to find an answer to:

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $A \subset H$.  We say $A$ is weakly bounded if for any $h_0 \in H$ we have $\sup \{|\langle h, h_0\rangle_H| : h \in A\} < \infty$.  It's very easy and classical to prove using the P.U.B. that a weakly bounded subset of $H$ is in fact bounded.  Of course via the isometric embedding of a normed space $X$ into $X^{**}$, a similar statement can be made for a normed vector space.

My question is whether there exists a $\textit{concrete}$ example of a Hilbert space (or a normed vector space) and a subset $A$ where proving $A$ is weakly bounded is much easier than proving directly $A$ is bounded? Or is this mainly a theoretical result?

Maybe to be more precise, I'm asking for a "weakly bounded vs bounded" example along the lines of the following classic closed graph theorem example [Backwards shift operator is bounded linear operator on Bergman space.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4134602/backwards-shift-operator-is-bounded-linear-operator-on-bergman-space) (though I don't necessarily need my example to be a space of holomorphic functions).

The point here being that I have no idea how to prove boundedness of the Backwards shift via the definition (especially if $p \neq 2$), and while maybe there's a clever way to do it, it's damn near trivial using the closed graph theorem.

A basic idea perhaps: There should be a situation in Elliptic PDE theory where you naturally form a weakly convergent sequence $\{u_n\}_{n = 1}^\infty \subseteq  W^{1, 2} (\Omega)$ for some open set $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ (maybe via some diagonalization procedure?) and it's important to know that in fact $\{u_n\}_{n = 1}^\infty$ is norm bounded?